# Компаратор для "С" строк юникода

Tags: c++, unicode

Можно использовать данный компаратор для "С" строк юникода?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class StrCmp
{
public:
    template <typename T> bool operator()
        (const T* p1, const T* p2) const
    {
        while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2)
            ++p1, ++p2;

        return *p2 > *p1;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const char32_t* a[]
    {
        U"ЁЁЁ",
        U"АААААА",
        U"А",
        U"ЁЁЁ",
        U"ЁЁЁЁЁЁЁ",
        U"ААА"
    };

    std::sort(a, a + 6, StrCmp() );

    return 0;
}
```

если нельзя то почему.

Comment: Можно, если вас не волнуют вопросы collate. (т.е. может оказаться что какая-то буква, например Ё меньше чем А). Для collate - нужна таблица веса.

Comment: где взять таблицу веса?